# Issues with postgreSQL subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have the following chunk of code, in which in trying to count the sales of beef, chicken and pork in each month of the last year (i also need to determine the market share of the meats each month)

```
SELECT
    CAST(EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(FULLDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS INT) AS month
FROM purchases_2020
JOIN categories ON purchases_2020.purchaseid = categories.purchase_id
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT (purchaseid) AS total_sales
    FROM purchases_2020
    JOIN categories ON purchases_2020.purchaseid = categories.purchase_id
    WHERE category = 'whole milk' OR category = 'yogurt' OR category = 'domestic eggs' 
    GROUP BY month
    ) a 
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

The expected result is the following image

[image]

**EDIT to add the exact error message**
but in getting this error message

```
syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 6:     SELECT
            ^
[SQL: SELECT
    CAST(EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(FULLDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS INT) AS month
FROM purchases_2020
JOIN categories ON purchases_2020.purchaseid = categories.purchase_id
    (
    SELECT
        COUNT (purchaseid) AS total_sales
    FROM purchases_2020
    JOIN categories ON purchases_2020.purchaseid = categories.purchase_id
    WHERE category = 'whole milk' OR category = 'yogurt' OR category = 'domestic eggs' 
    GROUP BY month
    ) a 
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

This is the data schema i'm working with.

[image]

**EDIT**

I'm aware i can query the total_sales like this:

```
SELECT
    CAST(EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM TO_TIMESTAMP(FULLDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')) AS INT) AS month,
    COUNT (purchaseid) AS total_sales
FROM purchases_2020
JOIN categories ON purchases_2020.purchaseid = categories.purchase_id
WHERE category = 'beef' OR category = 'pork' OR category = 'chicken' 
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month
```

But doing it like this locks me out of doing of writting the market_share formula on the select statement because of the WHERE statement no being inside a subquery.

Comment: What is the **exact** error message you get? (Please **[edit]** your question and add it)

Comment: added the exact error message

Comment: BTW: why do you store `FULLDATE` as a text column?

Comment: doind the extract without the cast gives me with a decimal number (1.0) and i want it to be an integer

Comment: `FULLDATE` should be a `timestamp` - never store timestamp, date or numbers in `text` columns.

Comment: Your timestamp must be timestamp if you run `select extract('month' from '20220101 12:00:00'::timestamp)` you get `1` for result. Why is `purchase_id` varchar ? I think int would be better... I ran your query and have no error message.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name noted, and thanks, will create a column of numbers instead

Comment: @Philippe which query you ran? the one with subquery in the FROM statement?

Comment: If you want to store a timestamp use the `timestamp` data type.

Comment: The error message doesn't match the query at the start of your question. That would result in "*subquery in FROM must have an alias*". However your error message indicates you actually use `FROM purchases_2020 (select ..) join` which should be `FROM purchases_2020 JOIN (select ...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name trying to mend the issue you pointed the error message changed, will edit the question to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you the count of sales by month and category. I can't test it because I don't have datas.

```
SELECT
    c.category,
    EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM FULLDATE) AS month,
    count(purchaseid) AS total_sales
FROM purchases_2020 p JOIN categories c ON p.purchaseid = c.purchase_id
WHERE category in ('beef','pork','chicken')
GROUP BY month,c.category
ORDER BY month,c.category;
```

Comment: Thanks, i looking for a way to introduce the where clause in a subquery that on affects the count(purchaseid)

Comment: @JoseArmas if you want a "WHERE clause" affecting `COUNT` you can try using conditional aggregation. For example, `COUNT(purchaseid) FILTER (WHERE category IN ('beef', 'pork', 'chicken'))`. Conditional Aggregation gets applied *after* you have a result set.